# determine SQL query of albums, and total videos

Tags: php, mysql, union

For the query i need to do, a user uploads videos onto an album, on their video page, it has the list of albums, and the total of videos below it.

Currently, what i am trying to do is a union, however this is not working, this is my code:

```
$query="SELECT albname, albcover, lid, NULL as vidcount FROM albums WHERE USERID='".mysql_real_escape_string($USERID)."' and verified='1'

UNION

SELECT NULL as albname, NULL as albcover, NULL as lid, count(*) as vidcount FROM albs_vids A LEFT JOIN albums B USING(ALBID) WHERE B.USERID='".mysql_real_escape_string($UID)."'";
```

So, what happens is the SQL query needs to find the data of the album, ie albname, albcover and lid from the table `albums`.  Then find the amount of videos in the table `albs_vids` which correspond to the album.  The album is specified by `ALBID` in both tables.

Comment: what is B.USERID? where is the B table?

Comment: edited in the fix, that should have been the table `albums`, but the query still doesnt work properly

Comment: in that case try to use inner join the two tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to completely understand what you're asking ,but this will give you the count of videos for each album that has your userid:

```
$sql = "SELECT a.albname, a.albcover, a.lid, COUNT(*) AS vidcount
FROM albums AS a
LEFT JOIN albs_vids AS b ON b.albid = a.albid
WHERE b.userid='".mysql_real_escape_string($UID)."'
GROUP BY a.albname";
```